# Get comment text in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this

```
var text = "/*var*/test/**/"
```

so I want to get that text in between comments (test)

I tried this

```
var search = new RegExp("/\*var\*/(.*?)/\*\*/");
result = text.match(search)
```

I get invalid regular expression error:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: //*var*/(.*?)/**//: Nothing to repeat
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the backslash one more time when passing your regex inside `"` delimiter.

```
var search = new RegExp("/\\*var\\*/(.*?)/\\*\\*/");
```

Example:

```
> var text = "/*var*/test/**/"
undefined
> var search = new RegExp("/\\*var\\*/(.*?)/\\*\\*/");
undefined
> console.log(search.exec(text)[1])
test
```

**OR**

Use the forward slash as delimiter but note that you must need to escape all the forward slashes.

```
> var search = /\/\*var\*\/(.*?)\/\*\*/;
undefined
> console.log(search.exec(text)[1])
test
```